# How to convert denominators in fraction equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I want to convert following equation:
$$\frac{x}{A} + \frac{y}{B} + \frac{z}{C} = D$$

To this equation:
$$qA + wB + rC = F$$

What I'm trying to ask is how to transfer $A$, $B$, and $C$ from denominator to numerator.

Comment: What are $q, w, r$, and $F$?

Comment: Sayid, what makes you think it is possible to do what you are asking? Instead, try to convince yourself that it's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way. Start with
$$
\frac{x}{A}+\frac{y}{B}+\frac{z}{C}=D
$$
Multiply both sides by $ABC$:
$$
xBC+yAC+zAB=ABCD
$$
Group terms:
$$
(xC)B+(yA)C+(zB)A=ABCD
$$
and you have $q=zB, w=xC, r=yA, F=ABCD$. Of course there are other ways to make these choices.

Comment: I suspected the OP was looking for a solution in which $q, w, r$ are independent from $A, B, C$.

Comment: @enzotib. Perhaps, but absent any further clarification from the OP, you will admit that it *is* a solution.

Comment: In fact, your first upvote is mine :)